# Use variables for columns in Range definition

Tags: excel, vba

I want to use the content of a range in an array. It works until I put in variables for the columns with Cells(R,C)-method in the range definition. So my problem is definitive in **Range(Cells(headline, ic_from_col), Cells(headline, ic_to_col))**

> Run time error '1004' Application or object-oriented error"  <

What am I missing? What could I try?

```
    Dim export As String: export = "Table1"
    Dim headline As Integer: headline = 7
    Dim ic_from_col As Integer: ic_from_col = 30
    Dim ic_to_col As Integer: ic_to_col = 40
    Dim ICNames As Variant: Set ICNames = Sheets(export).Range(Cells(headline, ic_from_col), Cells(headline, ic_to_col))
    Dim key As String: key = 1
    For Each item In SomethingElse
      ...
      name = ICNames(key)
    Next item
```

(I get the numbers for columns and row by searches. Which works, so I put just some numbers in here for that. Just to explain why I want to use variables).

I tried the following as recommended, but I've got the same result:

```
Dim ICNames As Variant
ICNames = Sheets(export).Range(Cells(headline, ic_from_col), Cells(headline, ic_to_col))
```

Let me show what works to explain my problem:

```
  Dim export As String: export = "Table"
    Dim headline As Long: headline = 7
    Dim ic_from_col As Long: ic_from_col = 32
    Dim ic_to_col As Long: ic_to_col = 42
    Dim ICNames As Variant: Set ICNames = Sheets(export).Range("AF" & headline & ": AQ" & headline)
'    Dim ICNames As Variant: Set ICNames = Sheets(export).Range(Cells(headline, ic_from_col), Cells(headline, ic_to_col))
    Dim key As String: key = 1
      Name = ICNames(key)
      MsgBox (Name)
```

Comment: a) *"I want to use the content of a range in an array".* - Assigning range data to a (datafield) array ICNames (which is no object!) doesn't require a `Set`, expected e.g. for declared range declarations. b) the resulting ICNames is a 1-based 2-dim datafield which you reference by `ICnames({row no},{column no})`.- Btw Always use `Option Explicit` to declare all variables, prefer using `Long` instead of `Integer`, especially for tabular row/column indices as you might exceed 65k limits (and VBA translates integers internally to Long anyway).

Comment: That is interesting, thank you! 
But I dont see where it would solve my problem?

Comment: Not sure if this is the exact problem, but very likely to cause problems - `Sheets(export).Range(Cells(headline, ic_from_col), Cells(headline, ic_to_col))` .  `Range` is in the `export` sheet, `Cells` is in whatever sheet is currently active.  If `Cells` isn't in the same sheet as `Range` it will throw an error.  `Sheets(export).Range(Sheets(export).Cells(...)`  or use [With... End With](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/with-end-with-statement)

Answer (score 0):

So, this is how I solved it for my case. I have used ".address":

```
ICNames = Sheets(export).Range(Cells(headline, ic_from_col).Address & ":" & Cells(headline, ic_to_col).Address)
```

Comment: So you decided to use a (datafield) **array** (thus no `Set ...`; c.f. comment to OP) which btw results in  a 1-based 2-dim array consisting here e.g. of elements in one row only; consequently you have to refer to `ICNames` via `ICNames(key, 1)` to get a valid element (*note* that VBA would expect numeric indices, but translates even your String input internally *without 'bleating'*).  It seems that you aren't too consistant in type declarations. If preferring to set range variables instead, then do declare them explicitly `As Range` and try to fully qualify *all* range references.

Answer (score -1):

If sheet name is correct then you need to remove Set keywork, since it is not object.

```
ICNames = Sheets(export).Range(Cells(headline, ic_from_col), Cells(headline, ic_to_col))
```

Comment: Still the same error message

`ICNames = Sheets(export).Range(Cells(headline, ic_from_col), Cells(headline, ic_to_col)) ´